# Poor wireless Conection Ubuntu 20.04 (Dual Boot)

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

On my laptop, I have a dual boot with windows 10 and Ubunti 20.04. My wifi internet speed is significantly faster on Windows than Ubuntu (220 Mbit/s vs 20 Mbit/s), and I can't seem to figure out why. When having a wired connection, there is no problem.

I've gone through multiple similar posts/blogs, and based on that tried the following:

1. Set `wifi.powersave = 2` at `etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`.
2. Used `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` (and also tried `=10`).
3. Set `hosts:          files dns` in  `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
4. Tried uninstalling `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` (but it wasn't installed)
5. Tried downloading `iwlwifi` manually (but the file was already present in `/lib/firmware`.
6. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling `iwldvm` via `sudo modprobe -rv iwldvm` and `sudo modprobe iwldvm`.

But none of them seem to give an improvement. Does anyone know where to look next and what to try? Because I'm out of ideas.

Some more information: `sudo lshw -class network -short && nmcli device status` when only having wifi connected, gives:

```
======================================================
/0/100/19        enp0s25    network        82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (L
/0/100/1c.3/0    wlo1       network        Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
wlo1     wifi      connected    Linksys100 
enp0s25  ethernet  unavailable  --         
lo       loopback  unmanaged    --
```

And  `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` gives:

```
25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 3e)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1101]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

`rfkill list all` gives:

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep iwl` gives

```
[   22.370678] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   22.370841] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   22.493735] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode failed with error -2
[   22.493757] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-5.ucode failed with error -2
[   22.533588] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: loaded firmware version 9.221.4.1 build 25532 op_mode iwldvm
[   23.202028] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   23.202036] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   23.202037] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   23.202039] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN, REV=0x74
[   23.246237] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   26.247797] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[  119.101220] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[  119.393473] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[  269.382438] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[  269.382946] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode failed with error -2
[  269.382956] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-5.ucode failed with error -2
[  269.383166] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: loaded firmware version 9.221.4.1 build 25532 op_mode iwldvm
[  269.405281] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[  269.405283] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[  269.405284] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[  269.405285] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN, REV=0x74
[  269.441553] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[  269.545729] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[  279.500566] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[  279.750440] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[  279.894389] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[  280.146902] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
```

As a sidenode, I've recently upgraded from 18.04 tot 20.04. However, I had similar problems beforehand. It should also be noted that this network is a mesh network, but (by heart) I can't remember this working better at other networks.

Comment: I did some digging and found [this link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html) that may interest you. The downloads have a readme in them that tell you how to apply the changes. It might be worth trying that.

Comment: @KGIII Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried to install it, but it seems like the driver is installed properly: the file is already installed in `libs\firmware`, and when running `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` it lists `iwlwifi` as the driver in use (see updated post). I've also tried to disable and enbale `iwldvm`, but network speed seems unaffected.